# How to pass variable value to next line in unix shell while using restic command in openshift

Tags: shell, openshift

I am logging into one of the pods and executing

```
oc exec example-nxcpj -- bash 
oc exec example-nxcpj --it -- bash
```

I am using below command to list locks and entering password in next line

```
restic list locks -r s3:https://s3.****amazonaws.com***/zen46
enter password for repository:
```

How do I make this in shell script dynamically passing password to above line?

my script is like below

```
oc exec example-nxcpj -- bash -c 'for i in /var/lib/; 
do export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*********;
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=********;
restic list locks -r s3:https://*****amazonaws.com****zen46;
done'
```

getting below error/warning

```
Fatal: an empty password is not a password
reading repository password from stdin
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't know `restic`, but from the error message, I conclude that restic reads stdin for the password. How about supplying the pwd via stdin, i.e. `restic <<<PASWORD list locks....`?

Comment: Can you eloborate the usage of it? @user1934428

Comment: Well, `<<<SOME_STRING` feeds `SOME_STRING` to the stdin of a command. Of course you should double check, whether this is indeed the expected way to pass the password here.  We would expect tools to have a more secure alternative for sending the password.